# React Native: How to have change button title and onPress function based on the status of the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list in which the user can add items with the 'Add' Button, and I want to make the 'Add' Button become the 'Delete' Button after the user click once. My thought is to set a boolean value for items to keep track of whether it is in the list, but how can I change the title and onPress function of the Button? What's the appropriate way to implement it in React Native? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to add a delete button on each item?

Comment: Yea. If the item is added to the list, the button of that item will delete it from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your status of your object in state and your `text` and `onPress` function of your button will change automatically when your object status changed.

Something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress=(this.state.status ? () => addFunction() : () => deleteFunction())>
    {(this.state.status) ? "Add" : "Delete"}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And when user click on your item, just simply set status state

```
function itemClick() {
     // Do something

     this.setState({
         status: false
     })
}
```